# Adding where clientid=x kills execution time of SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, pagination

I have this query that works very fast on a large dataset:

```
SELECT q2.* FROM 
    (SELECT q1.*, ROWNUM AS rn 
    FROM (
            SELECT name AS clientname,to_char(callstart+gmt/24,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS callDate, 
                name AS destination,callno AS dialedNumber,ani AS accountAndCallingNumber,bduration AS duration,  
                to_char(callstart+gmt/24,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS formattedCallDate,  
                switchid, lineno, fileid
            FROM cdr 
                JOIN client
                ON client.id=cdr.aniclientid
                JOIN destination
                ON destination.id=cdr.destinationid
                JOIN country
                ON destination.countryid=country.id
                JOIN destinationgroup
                ON destinationgroup.id=destination.parentid
            WHERE callstart >= TO_DATE('01/30/2005 06:56:41','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                AND callstart < TO_DATE('07/16/2015 06:56:41','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
            ORDER BY callstart DESC
        ) q1
     ) q2
WHERE rn >= 0 AND ROWNUM <= 10
```

This executes in about 150 ms. But, when I add in the line

```
AND aniclientid=363
```

above ORDER BY callstart, the query becomes really slow, to the point where it is not usable.

What is the most elegant way to fix this?

Can it be done without adding an index? Adding one may be politically difficult.

If not, would an index on aniclientid fix it or would I need one on callstart as well? I believe a bitmap index would be right for the aniclient column since there are only about 1800 values. Would an index like this take much space?

I'm a bit new to SQL, especially indexes... Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the query plan before adding the additional predicate?  What is the query plan after adding the additional predicate?  What indexes are already created?  How selective are the various predicates?

Comment: Replacing ON client.id=cdr.aniclientid with ON client.id=cdr.aniclientid AND aniclientid=363 didn't make any difference. I'll add that info to the question Justin

Comment: Please run these commands: `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR your_query` and then `SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.display )`, and copy-paste (as a text) a result of last command to the question. These commands show an explain plan for the query.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you tomorrow on that one, there doesn't seem to be  a plan table set up yet. Bear with me.